# Conditional hint in sproc

Tags: sql-server

Other that duplicating a query in an sproc, is there any way to specify a hint based on an sproc parameter?  For example, with parameter `@waitForLock`, if it's set to 0 I want to use the `READPAST` hint, otherwise wait/block until the other transaction completes.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that.  I'd expect you'd need an IF/ELSE with 2 queries (one with the lock, one without)

Comment: @Joe: Yeah, I was thinking of the 2 queries since obviously a `CASE` statement wouldn't work.  If this were another type of hint (e.g. `NOLOCK`), maybe you could do a conditional isolation level: `IF @nolock = 1 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ UNCOMMITTED ELSE SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ COMMITTED`... then do your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I like the `OPTION RECOMPILE` suggestion, though that means it will recompile every time, even if stats or your parameter haven't changed. This is usually to thwart parameter sniffing, not help with cases where you want to avoid or not avoid taking locks.

One idea is to use dynamic SQL (which can also be beneficial depending on your "optimize for ad hoc workloads" setting and the frequency you run with one parameter or the other).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
    @waitForLock BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SET @sql = 'SELECT something FROM dbo.somewhere';

   IF @waitForLock = 0
      SET @sql = @sql + ' WITH (READPAST)';

   SET @sql = ' WHERE <some condition> ...';

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Comment: True, I hadn't thought about dynamic SQL, but that would work.  I ended up realizing that in my specific implementation, waiting for the other transaction (not doing `READPAST`) really didn't help.  The first transaction updates a column value, which would mean I wouldn't get a result anyway, so I might as well quit as early as possible.  The only exception to this is if the first transaction rolls back, which would only occur on error and is very unlikely.